# Kafka listener not working for spring test

Tags: kotlin, testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have the following class to handle account update kafka events

```
@Component
class AccountUpdateQueueListener(
    private val accountUpdateUseCase: AccountUpdateUseCase
) {
    @KafkaListener(
        topics = [Topics.ACCOUNT_UPDATES],
        groupId = "api",
        containerFactory = "accountUpdatesConsumeFactory",
    )
    fun onAccountUpdate(
        @Payload request: AccountUpdateEventMessage,
        @Header("_txId") txId: String,
        acknowledgment: Acknowledgment
    ) {
        MDC.put("account_id", request.account.id.toString())
        MDC.put("_txId", txId)
        try {
            accountUpdateUseCase.update(AccountUpdateEventMessage.toCommand(request))
            acknowledgment.acknowledge()
        } catch (e: AccountNotFoundException) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I am trying to test the `accountUpdateUseCase.update` function used in `onAccountUpdate` function is called with this test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("testing")
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = ["listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092"])
class AccountUpdateQueueListenerTest {
    @MockK
    lateinit var accountUpdateUseCase: AccountUpdateUseCase

    @InjectMockKs
    lateinit var accountUpdateQueueListener: AccountUpdateQueueListener

    @Autowired
    lateinit var kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, AccountUpdateEventMessage>

    val accountUpdateEventMessage = AccountUpdateEventMessage(
        ...
    )
    @BeforeEach
    fun init() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    }
    @Test
    fun `no errors and update is entered`() {
        kafkaTemplate.send(Topics.ACCOUNT_UPDATES, "", accountUpdateEventMessage)
        verify(exactly = 1) { accountUpdateUseCase.update(any()) }
    }
}
```

The tests failed as `accountUpdateUseCase.update`. When running this with a debugger it is clear that `onAccountUpdate` is never entered. However, if the test case is rewritten as follows the debugger actually stopped in `onAccountUpdate`

```
    @Test
    fun `no errors and update is entered`() {
        kafkaTemplate.send(Topics.ACCOUNT_UPDATES, "", accountUpdateEventMessage)
        verify(exactly = 1) { accountUpdateQueueListener.onAccountUpdate(any(),any(),any()) }
    }
```

My questions are why does the debugger stop in the second test case and how can I rewrite the first test to achieve my original goal?

Comment: Seems like you need to add some delay before verifying. Consumer does not poll messages instantly.

Comment: Put send inside a runBlocking scope with delay of 5 seconds, didn't change the outcome. Thank you for your response, in any case